# Laravel: Images will not load up on virtual server

Tags: php, html, laravel, server

Right so I have completed my website and I put it on to the virtual server. Everything except the images work fine. On my local host the images load up but on the virtual server they do not load up.

Here is the block of code that displays the image(s):

```
@foreach($post->images()->get() as $image) <!-- loops through all the images that have the post id of this post as foreign key -->
   <div class="row">
       <div class="col-md-12">
           <img id="event-image" style="width: 600px; height: 450px;" src="{{ asset('storage/cover_images/' . $image->cover_image) }}"> <!-- displays the image on the current loop -->
       </div>
   </div>
@endforeach
```

Do you have to do something different to the path when using a server? When I do inspect element it looks fine.

Comment: Where do you have them saved locally? Which directoy? Do you have them in `./storage` and using symlinks to display in public?

Comment: Yes, I have used a link, when an image is saved it is saved in 2 locations storage and public. I have not changed the directory from when I moved it from local to a server. If it is working locally why is it not working on the server? @devk

Comment: Check on your server if the images are present in your storage folder

Comment: Oh that is strange the image is not added to /public/storage/cover_image/ but it is added to /storage/app/public/cover_image, What happened to the link?@devk

Comment: Did you run `php artisan storage:link` on you server?

Comment: How would I be able to do that on windows for a server?

Comment: Is your server Windows? Never dealt with Windows servers myself, do you get an error if you run the command?

Comment: no, it is a linux server but I have no idea how to set up the link for it. I know how to do it locally but not on the server.

Comment: Run `php artisan storage:link` on the server

Comment: You need to login to your server via `ssh` and then cd into you project directory and then you need to run `php artisan storage:link`